# Read same tag twice NFC in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, nfc

I'm trying to develop a communication workflow between phone and NFC microcontroller (powered by energy harvesting). The microcontroller starts by identifying itself via NFC and expects a request written to it. It can process the request and then write the response to the tag. This part is working just fine in my microcontroller and flutter app using the nfc_in_flutter plugin. However, I don't know how to read the tag again after the controller wrote the response. Re-scanning the tag or restarting the stream would interrupt the power supply of the microcontroller, leading to a restart and loss of the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to continue reading after reading a Ndef message using the `nfc_in_flutter` plugin on Android, it is just not designed to do this.

It is totally possible to do what you want with native code.

So write your flutter app to call the native code in a correct manner to do what you want or write your own plugin or there might be other plugins that do what you need.

Update:

The reason why is because the plugin when notified by the OS about a Tag, connects to the Tag, reads the Ndefmessage and then closes the connection. After the `close` no further I/O is possible.

Comment: Bummer... But thanks, I'll checkout some other plugins then.